# R -- Vignettes that are not made by Sweave possible?

Tags: r, packaging, vignette

Can I include some PDF in the pkg/doc folder so that the `vignette` function works, but no corresponding Rnw, Rtex, etc exists?

I am thinking of slides or documents containing markdown text weaved with R chunks, which have a different build process and hence different file extensions.

The writing R extensions guide suggests that it should be possible to include documents which can not be build at installation time, but the `vignette` function seems to look for files with special extensions (Rnw, Rtex, etc) and also for a file called `vignette.rds`.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: why don't you just set up a tiny package and try it to see if it works?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do... I am stuck.

Comment: FWIW, `?vignette` says that `Currently, only PDF versions of vignettes can be viewed.` Everything else is there for the user to find on his or her own. In that case, `browseVignettes` may be of help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked about this several years ago, and while Fritz Leisch is amenable to the idea, he hasn't had the time to implement it.

Comment: Ah, so when will we see your Swv2 replacement?

Comment: Whichever, I'll just count the underscores you'll sprinkle into command names :)

Answer (score 5):

(Cross-posted from a [response I just left on R-help](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/28448):)

As a workaround, you could include your own `xvignette` function in your package: see below.
It won't show you indices, but it will pick up any appropriately named file that you include in the `inst/doc` directory of your
package ...

```
xvignette <- function(vname,pkg,ext="pdf") {
   vname <- paste(vname,ext,sep=".")
   fn <- system.file("doc",vname,package=pkg)
   if (nchar(fn)==0) stop("file not found")
   utils:::print.vignette(list(pdf=fn))
   invisible(fn)
 }
```

You'll have to somehow alert your package users to the fact that this alternative documentation exists -- perhaps in the help file for the package itself.

You might fill in the default value of `pkg` above with your package name to make it easier on the user: I thought about using some variant of `getPackageName(environment(xvignette))` to do it automatically, but that seems too complicated ...

Brian Ripley also mentioned in his response to the question that:

> At present vignette() means Sweave documents, as only they have 
>   metadata like titles.  This is planned to be changed soon.

... but I don't know what "soon" means (it will be about 6 months until 2.14.0 comes out, I think)

**edit**: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/28449 details another workaround (creating a dummy vignette that incorporates the existing PDF file)

**edit 2**: And

- here's what Yihui Xie has to say about [including knitr-based vignettes in packages](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/) (essentially another "dummy vignette" strategy)
- [vignette about non-Sweave vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/vignettes/NonSweaveVignettes.pdf) from the `R.rsp` package

Comment: Six months til 2.14.0? Isn't it usually April and October?

Comment: I guess so.  I was thinking about the recent 2.13.1 release and forgetting that it's 6 months between .0 releases, not point releases.  So only 2.5 months.

Answer (score 5):

This is supported natively as of R 3.0.0, see http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/.

Instructions to use `knitr` as vignette engine boil down to:

> 1. add `%\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}` to the `Rnw` source document (note you still need `%\VignetteIndexEntry{}` as before)
> 2. specify `VignetteBuilder: knitr` in the package DESCRIPTION file
> 3. add `Suggests: knitr` in `DESCRIPTION` if `knitr` is needed only for vignettes

See also the [official R documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Non_002dSweave-vignettes) on that topic.